# Hide 3party empty namespaces

Tags: vb.net

When I add an 3party Library (Gibraltar.Agent) to a VB.NET project I get namespaces which interfere with my current code.

For example the namespace Gibraltar.Agent.IS makes the following code invalid:

```
  Assert.That("bla", [Is].EqualTo("bla"))
```

as a solution i have to fully qualify [Is]

```
  Assert.That("bla", Nunity.Frameworks.Is.EqualTo("bla"))
```

Also annoying is the "I" namespace, which makes the following invalid:

```
  For i = 0 to 10 'valid without referencing Gibraltar.Agent
  For i as Integer = 0 to 10 'needed change after adding Gibraltar.Agent
```

How can i hide the unwanted 3Party namespaces?

[image]

**EDIT**

- I did not add any Gibraltar namespaces.
- The following does not help either:

  ```
  Imports [Is] = NUnit.Framework.Is
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These odd namespaces are created by an obfuscation library used by an older version of [VistaDB](http://www.VistaDB.net) which is ILMerged into the Gibraltar Agent. The obfuscator substitutes two-character symbols for VistaDB namespaces to conserve space.

We acquired VistaDB last year and now have a free hand to rework its internal structure and build process.  This issue with namespaces leaking through will be resolved in Gibraltar 3.0.

Jay Cincotta
Founder
[Gibraltar Software](http://GibraltarSoftware.com)

Comment: And it's gone!  We killed all of these off in Gibraltar 3.0 which shipped March 31st of 2012.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new Class Library and create [wrappers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_library) around the Gibraltar.Agent functionality you use, then just reference this class library instead of Gibraltar.Agent from your other projects.

See also the [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Comment: Yep this would work, great idea I like it! I keep the question open, since it is a work around and I would like to see if there is an explanation for the problem - which seems to be totally odd - at least from my point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Just don’t `Import` that namespace in your files. You may need to change the project settings if you have at some time in the past activated that namespace for inclusion in your project settings.

But according to [the documentation](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/support/Documentation/Gibraltar.Agent~Gibraltar.Agent_namespace.html) the objectionable names don’t even exist.

Comment: No I didn't import the namespace. I just reference the assembly and the compiler errors come up immediately. When I look at the project settings below "references", the namespaces related to Gibraltar aren't checked neither.

Comment: @Robert Hmm. In that case, get rid of the library or complain to the maintainer. This is inacceptable behaviour in a library.

Comment: @Konrad: I really like the product! And I can't see how they did wrong. The behavior is completely unexpected, since the namespace is no where imported. It just doesn't make any sense!

Comment: Its possible that their Is class is in the global namespace rather than in Gibraltar.Agent, this would explain how this is happening but does not provide any clear solution.

Comment: @Patrick this would be really crappy :-) (But I guess its a namespace problem, since the object browser and intellisense show the IS namespace.)

Comment: Ah its an Is namespace, I see - Nasty Gibraltar!